# Show that the $\sup S=1/2$ where $S= \{(-1)^n/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Show that the sup(S) where $S = \{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is sup(S) = $\frac{1}{2}$

Attempt:

In order to show $\frac{1}{2}$ is the supremum I must show:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists s\in S \ such\ that \\ \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon < s < \frac{1}{2}$$

So from this statement what I gather is I have to find an '**s**'  that would be a function of $\epsilon$.

My question is how do I find that **s**?

I think what I should do is given an element $s \in S$ is of the form $$\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$$

Just solve $$\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$$

But then in this expression there is no **s**. So am I solving for **s** or $\epsilon$?

Comment: Isn't $\frac12\in S$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes and I do know that if a set has a maximal element, then that element will be the Supremum, but I want to go through the process of showing it the way above, so I get practice in this procedure since it is common to many analysis proofs.

Comment: You are confused as regards the definition.  The set $[0,1]\cup {24}$ has sup $=24$.  But $24$ is not a limit point of elements in the set.

Comment: @lulu I think the definition that dc3rd wrote is correct and holds in the case of $24$ you mentioned. This definition is correct for the supremum of any set of real numbers.

Comment: @vkonton  No...in my case there is no element $s$ of my set which satisfies, say, $24-1<s<24$, where of course I have taken $\epsilon =1$.  Similarly, in the OP's actual case, taking $\epsilon =.01$, there is no $s$ in the given set such that $.5-.01<s<.5$

Comment: @lulu I think that the strict inequality is the problem.

Comment: @vkonton of course!  But, more broadly, it is an (oft-made) mistake to use subtle methods where much cruder ones work.  The subtle definition of a supremum is needed when the least upper bound of a set is not actually in the set.  When it is in the set, one can confirm that it works much more easily.  All you need is to prove that every other element in the set is less  than it!

Comment: @vkonton  Worth noting, I think, that the OP's definition is more badly flawed than you are allowing.  Suppose my set $S$ did have the property that, for any $\epsilon >0$ I could exhibit $s\in S$ such that $\frac 12-\epsilon<s<\frac 12$.  All that would show was that $\frac 12$ was an accumulation point of elements in $S$...it would in no way imply that $\frac 12$ was the sup.   You still have to prove that no element in $S$ exceeds $\frac 12$ but if you have shown that then you are already done.

Comment: @lulu Yes, you're right. I just assumed that OP wanted to use the $\epsilon$ definion of supremum and did not pay much attention to its details.

Comment: @vkonton, you are both right. I was being sloppy in the way that I stated the definition because I wanted to arrive at the 2 step that  wrote down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken in your characterization of the supremum. To show $\sup S=\frac12$, you must show two things:

1. For all $s\in S$, $s\le \frac12$. [This means $\frac12$ is an upper bound]
2. For all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $s\in S$ so $s>\frac12-\epsilon$. [This means there can be no smaller upper bounds].

Here are the proofs:

1. If $n$ is odd, then $(-1)^n/n<0<\frac12$. If $n$ is even, so $n\ge 2$, then $(-1)^n/n=1/n\le \frac12$.
2. Choose $s = \frac12\in S$. Then $s=\frac12>\frac12-\epsilon$.

Comment: I agree with your proof, this is the idea that I was trying to articulate. How would I show this if for some reason my choice supremum was not in my set? How would I find the existence of an element **s** then?

Comment: @dc3rd The method to find $s$ will vary from problem to problem. For example, to prove $\sup\{-1/n\mid n\in \mathbb N\}=0$, then given $\epsilon>0$, you need to find $n$ so $-\frac1n>-\epsilon$. Here, any $n>\frac1\epsilon$ works.

Answer (score 3):

The supremum of a set is, first of all, an upper bound of the set.
It is very easy to check that for any $s \in S$ it holds that $1/2 \geq s$.
Set $s^* = 1/2$. We will show that $s^*$ using the definition you mentioned.

We already proved that $s^* \geq s$ for any $s \in S$.
Now let $\epsilon >0$. Then we know that $1/2 \in S$ and
moreover, $s^* - \epsilon < 1/2$. Therefore we found an element of the
set that is greater than $s^* -\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Thus, $s^*=1/2$
is the supremum.

Comment: How do we know $s^* - \epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$? Or is it that when you set $s^*$ you meant to say "set $s^* = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: There was a typo, $s^* = 1/2$ not $2$. Yes, you're right.

Comment: So what is "the element" that is greater than $s^* - \epsilon$? It is that element that I am trying to figure out exists.

Comment: $1/2$ is this element. $1/2 > 1/2 -\epsilon$.

Comment: But doesn't the element have to be different to what we propose as the l.u.b?

Comment: No, this is actually the mistake in your definition that Mike Earnest mentioned.